# Should we store data in an intermediary database in stateless stream processing?

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, bigdata, spark-streaming, stream-processing

i'm working on a study case that consists on proposing a technical architecture for a real-time stream processing problem. the problem is that a transportation company wants to track in near real-time the speed and the number of passengers in its buses. 
The initial architecture that i proposed is like this :

1. Buses send data into a MQQT Server in real time
2. Apache Kafka gets data from this server through an MQQT connector
3. calculation of "speed" and "Number of passengers" using Kafka Streams API or Spark streaming
4. Visualization of "speed" and "Number of passengers".

My questions are the following

- the architecure, is it correct ?
- the stream processing problem in this case, is it stateless ?
- and finally, i would like to know if i have to store data in an intermediary database like cassandra before doing the vizualisation ?
- if no, is there an open source visualization tool that can interact directly with streams in motion ?

Comment: Architecture is sound. For calculating speed / num. of passengers you can use KStreams. i.e. see http://www.landoop.com/blog/2017/10/lenses-sql-count/

Stream processing is stateless - for visualization tool have a look at https://www.landoop.com/docs/lenses/developers - it's free for developers